# Why can only one user be notified?

Tags: discussion, comment-replies

When you are commenting on a question and you want to notify two or more people you get the following error:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

Why can you only notify one person (except the owner)? Sometimes I want to notify more people.

(Say I've posted a comment that's wrong. Within seconds multiple users will also post a comment pointing out that I am terribly wrong. After a while, I visit Stack Overflow again and I want to apologize. At this moment I would have to post multiple comments to apologize. Why is the comment system designed in this way?)

Comment: Don't apologise to users one by one. Just acknowledge your mistake for feature readers to see it.

Comment: @Stijn Thank you, I know this and will acknowledge my mistakes. This scenario was only an example. There are plenty of situations where you want to notify more people :)

Comment: Probably to prevent stuff like @guyt "@"stijn "@"ChrisF "@"anyone else that has commented on here, can someone help me? Leave your comment and, if the person is interested in coming back to your post, they will.

Comment: You want to discuss things with more than one user? Write more than one comment!

Comment: @codeMagic That reason seems legit..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general if you find yourself wanting to address lots of people in comments you're doing it 
wrong. Comments are not meant for extended discussions, but to ask for clarification/point out possible mistakes/etc.

In your (now deleted example) the simple answer is just to delete your original comment and move on. You could flag the comments that point out your mistake as obsolete but that would be making work for the moderators.

Cluttering up the comments with lots of "@user sorry about that" comments is just adding to the noise and hiding potentially useful comments.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it was not for this particular situation. I've edited my question. You have to see it more in general: why can you only notify one person?

Comment: Deleting the comment may make other comments meaningless. In this case you shouldn't delete the comment or delete your comment and ask moderators to remove related comments [Flagging makes comment meaningless](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152142).

Comment: I think you overlooked one case, If I commented on a question and the OP didn't `@` me, I wouldn't know the OP replied to me.