# Why can't I comment on an answer to my Stack Overflow post?

Tags: discussion

I'm getting the error shown below when trying to comment on an answer to one of my posts:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified

[image: error message]

### Why is the error occurring?

This question is slightly different from: [Why can only one user be notified?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274872/why-can-only-one-user-be-notified) which assumes the reader understands that the `@` symbol is triggering a ping.  I didn't know that prior to this post.

When I search on this string in Stack Overflow I get only one post, where this specific question is not answered:
[Rails 4, content not displaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026339/rails-4-content-not-displaying/18026819#18026819)

If I search in http://meta.stackoverflow.com I do get the answers I'm looking for (another bonus lesson learned!).

This search gives me exactly the information I'm looking for:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=only+one+additional+%40user+can+be+notified%3B+the+post+owner+will+always+be+notified.

Comment: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: So what is the *full* content of the comment? We cannot see the first half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's write that you are trying to "ping" some people (@ user_name). You can only ping one (or two) people on a comment.

Comment: This question belongs on meta, not on main. This question has been migrated, but please hold off on answering off-topic questions until they have found the correct home.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Thanks, I am trying to say that I am using the (at)Startup and (at)RolesAllowed annotations and that must be being interpreted as a pings.  How do I say (at)Startup and have it interpreted as the (at)symbol?

Comment: @John: use a backslash (\@Startup), or better still, mark up the text as code with backticks (`@Startup`).

Comment: \@Backslash works (kindof). backtick (the character under the ~ on my keyboard) works perfectly. `@Thanks`!