# "Only one additional @user can be notified; " should be a warning, not an error

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

I wrote a comment, replying to a particular user. It contained another @ in the text.

> @AliBeadle:  I don't think, that reviewers will be notified if you
>   will mention them by  @name  in comment.

I tried to submit it and received

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always
>   be notified

I tried a few times, but the same message prevented me to submit the comment. Finally I realized that I can put '@name' in quotes.

It shouldn't be a blocking error. Instead it could be done as a  warning, e.g.

> Only the first additional user @User1 will be notified; the post
>   owner will always be notified. Continue?

Alternatively to avoid confirmation question it can be

> Only the first additional user @User1 will be notified; the post
>   owner will always be notified. You can address extra users in separate
>   comments

Related question:
[Why can only one user be notified?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274872/why-can-only-one-user-be-notified)

Answer (score 3):

I'm overcoming this in cases I want to notify any additional user aside the OP, but make it clear in my comment that OP is addressed by putting the OP's address in italics: `_@OP_`.

There's actually no option to address more users within a comment though.